# Facebook APP in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on an app for facebook using cakephp.

I created an app and added canvas url details:

```
My Domain : http://fbapp.example.com/
Canvas URL: http://fbapp.example.com/
Secure Canvas URL: https://fbapp.example.com/
```

I am trying to capture the current session. When I run the app, I see the following error in console.

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a sub-domain of one of the App's domains.
```

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Try googling the error message. It comes from facebook and is telling you that your facebook-application config is wrong.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I miss spelled my app url. Not sure how to close the question.

Comment: Either answer it, or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, There was a spelling mistake in the app URL.

For any one who has or ever will have any such issue. Please please and please recheck each and every URL while creating the app.

Thanks for the support:  @AD7six